# TypeError: (): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported: 1. (self: fasttext_pybind.args, arg0: float) -> None

Tags: python, fasttext

I would like Model training with `train.py` file, but I keep getting the following error:

```
setattr(a, k, v)
TypeError: (): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
1. (self: fasttext_pybind.args, arg0: float) -> None

Invoked with: <fasttext_pybind.args object at 0x7f6bbed0c030>, 
'/home/van/Download/classification/egs/vntc_fasttext/snapshots/model'
```

This is my code:

```
import argparse
import os
import sys
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath

import fasttext

cwd = dirname(abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(dirname(dirname(cwd)))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("train.py")
parser.add_argument("--train", help="train data path", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-s", "--serialization-dir", help="directory in which to save the model 
and its logs",required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

train_path = os.path.abspath(join(cwd, args.train))
serialization_dir = os.path.abspath(join(cwd, args.serialization_dir))

fasttext.train_supervised(train_path, '{}/model'.format(serialization_dir))
print("Done!!!")
```

Could someone please help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the fact that the method is expecting learning rate number, instead of the output path string (see [train_supervised parameters](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/python-module.html#train_supervised-parameters)).

Python module is slightly different from command line interface (see [supervised tutorial](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html) and [help on Python module](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/python-module.html)).

To train the model, use the following command:

```
model=fasttext.train_supervised(input=train_path)
```

Then, to save the model, use:

```
model.save_model('{}/model'.format(serialization_dir))
```